# How does the weak version of the Whitney embedding theorem follow from the strong version?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

If I understand the [Whitney embedding theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem) properly, then the strong version (loosely) says that any $m$-dimensional manifold can be smoothly embedded into $\mathbb{R}^{2m}$. The weak version (loosely) says that any continuous function from an $m$-dimensional manifold to an $(n>2m)$-dimensional manifold can be approximated by a smooth embedding.

But it isn't clear to me that the weak version follows from the strong version. On the one hand, the strong version is clearly "stronger" in the sense that the target manifold only needs to be $2m$-dimensional, while the weak version allows higher -dimensional target spaces and so is indeed weaker. But on the other hand, the strong version requires that the target manifold be Euclidean space, while the weak version allows for an arbitrary target manifold. So in this sense, the strong version of the theorem actually seems weaker than the weak version.

To me, the strong version looks stronger than the weak version in terms of the dimensionality counting, but weaker than the weak version in terms of the target manifold's allowed geometry - so it isn't clear that either version of the theorem directly implies the other. Is there an easy way to prove the weak version of the theorem using only the strong version?

Comment: I'm used to the "weak" Whitney Embedding Theorem providing an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{2m+1}$.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon So you're saying that Wikipedia's statement of the weak version of the WET is nonstandard and stronger than the standard statement? I certainly see why the strong version of the WET would imply the weak version as stated in your comment.

Comment: It is is nonstandard, and clearly encompasses the standard version, but I'm not sure if it's much stronger. My gut feeling is that the two version of the WET are proved by similar techniques: Sard's theorem for transversality and a dimension-counting argument in tangent spaces works to deform a continuous map into being an embedding (in the standard version of the WET, one shows that starting with a super-high-dimensional embedding, a generic projection into $\mathbb{R}^{2m+1}$ preserves injectivity).

Comment: To add to that: what makes the stronger version harder is that the dimension-counting argument fails. Intuitively: two curves can easily be pushed off each other in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by just deforming in a third direction, in $\mathbb{R}^2$ you need to be smarter about how to eliminate such intersections.

Comment: @ElchananSolomon Hm, interesting. I take your point that the version stated in Wikipedia may not be too much stronger than the standard version, but it really rubs me the wrong way that the wiki article only strengthens the weak version but not the strong version, such that the strong version no longer directly implies the stated form of the weak version.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you, that's not good math writing.

Comment: Yes, the strong version does not imply the (approximation form) of the weak version. The issues one is facing in the proofs are quite different. My suggestion is to read the proofs of both results and ignore what Wikipedia is saying (in general, Wikipedia's articles should be only treated as "the 1st approximation" of the actual math results).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Indeed - and then Math Stack Exchange often refines that to a second-order approximation. :-)